# Flag users who approve an edit that ends up rejected for vandalism

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, spam, review-suspension

If an edit is rejected as vandalism, I think it would be useful to have some sort of flag or notification raised if anyone voted to approve it.

Comment: Alternate title: Allow minitech to find users to ban from review easier

Comment: A fifteen-year-old moderator with 207 reputation on meta should be allowed to ban anyo... wait...

Comment: @Frédéric: minitech appears to be [allergic to metarep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160410/minitech?tab=bounties), keeps dumping the stuff all over the place.

Comment: @Mat, it indeed looks so (my previous comment was in jest of course, I routinely see minitech in action on SO so I know he fully deserves his diamond).

Comment: I wonder how many flags the Community user would get?

Comment: 4 status-completed and 1 status-planned tags in 23 bounties, not bad. (for comparison, my 15 status-completed in 108 mean about 1,5 less efficient investment)

Comment: I completely agree with the sentiment but why are you mentioning flags? This should be easy to automate; you can ban the approver for 7 days, give them a notification linking to the edit and a link to flag the offending post if they disagree with the ban.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I thought we’d especially want to know if somebody does this repeatedly, so…

Answer (score 8):

I think an auto-flag for moderators is the right way to handle this (not an auto-ban).  Since this question was asked SE has added several other auto-flags, so this would fit right in.  We have auto-flags for many comments (in a short time), many answers, many edits to the same post, rollback wars, and some others.  More recently we've gotten an auto-flag when a user has several validated rude/offensive or not-constructive comment flags.  In all of these cases, sometimes the information is noise and sometimes it requires moderator attention -- to lock a post, contact a user about rudeness, protect a question, or... with this change, ban a user from reviews.

We'd need to tune this with data.  I don't think we want to raise a flag if *one* user said vandalism and *one* approved on a single post.  Maybe two vandalism votes should raise a flag on the approving user, or maybe it should take more than one incident -- this depends on how often this happens and how severe it is.  If that edit actually gets through, I assume the community will see and flag it -- so we're concerned about approvals that were prevented from taking effect.  That feels similar to validated rude/offensive flags to me, where we raise a flag if it happens a few times, but comments are more frequent than errant edit reviews.

Comment: I feel bad about posting a suggestion (as opposed to having an actual fix) on a bountied question.  I'm only aware of the question at all because of the bounty, and I hope that somebody from SE will say something more authoritative (and positive :-) ) and collect said bounty.

Comment: Well, you can always give the rep back, even here on the same question. :)