# Is this suggested edit approved right?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

The below is a link to the post on Stack Overflow where I answered a users question.

[How to send data from fragment to fragment within same fragment activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653359/how-to-send-data-from-fragment-to-fragment-within-same-fragmentactivity/22653391#22653391)

I suggested an answer and posted links to the docs which has code snippets. The user accepted the answer before the suggested edit by the user himself was approved.

Then yesterday the user wanted to share something with me and instead of posting his code as an answer or a edit to the question edited my answer. The edit was approved.

So is the suggested edit approve right?. Should the user not post it as another answer altogether?

This is what the user posted

> this is what i got from doc & few searches so i want to share with you

And this is the link to the review suggested edits.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4450296

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, two points.

### That suggested edit changed too much.

90% of the answer is new. The edit should have been rejected. But, well, it was approved. And your name is attached to it. Are you happy with it? Leave it alone. Not so much? Roll it back.

I wish this sort of thing didn't happen, but it happens all the time. Approval seems to be the default response to suggested edits. But, that's been discussed [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits), [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything) times before, and there's not been a lot of activity directed towards dialing back access to either the queue, or reviews of the queue. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits) change would be an awesome step.

### Your answer wasn't really very good.

Two sentences, and a link to some documentation, was your answer. At first glance, the suggested edit looks like a *pretty good change*. It's got some code. Assuming it works (bit rusty with Java), it'll help future visitors more than your answer would have. Do that, more often.

Comment: fair enough i should have added some code snippets. i will edit with an example

Comment: Edited added code snippets and snap shots. I think if i had posted code snippets before op would not have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

No. I don't think an edit should completely change the context of the answer. That edit completely changed the quality, and context of the answer to a degree that is so extreme it should not have been approved.

Comment: right. probably it should have been an edit to the question or altogether posted a answer of his own