# Block an edit already proposed by same user and rejected by reviewers

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

As mentioned in a comment on an [other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits)

> Indeed. There are some either really stubborn or really stupid users who keep **suggesting the same edit** to the same post over and over again until it gets approved by some unwitting robo-reviewers. –  [BoltClock's a Unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) Feb 18 at 17:24

## My idea

So that why I think it will be great to block users to suggest same edit twice if the first one was already rejected by reviewers...

I know that it would store a lot of datas, but maybe with a lifetime for storing old edits, you will be able to avoid most of bad re-edit!

## Alternative proposal

So thanks to comments, an acceptable solution can be implemented :
`edit-bans` like `flag-bans` which have already proved its usefulness.

The idea is to suspend the suggest-edit right after some warnings if the user get too many declined edits in the same question. The right may be suspended generally or only for the targeted post...

Comment: Suggested edits are already kept even if rejected (at least for a while), I don't think this would increase data store size. (But would increase complexity/cost of course.)

Comment: No, sometimes a good edit is being rejected, so auto blocking isn't a good idea in my opinion. I would prefer to have some kind of automatic moderator flag when same edit is rejected 2-3 times in a row, so a mod can warn the "offending" user.

Comment: @JoDev : What about making edit-bans instead, if too many suggested-edits are rejected, like with flag-bans? In flagging, good flags can also be rejected.

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, why not! But in my mind, I was thinking more of an automated process! To limit human's charge...

Comment: @ShadowWizard : I understand that, but if the same user has editted few times the same post, and was rejected each time, I think that this edit could be flag as bad, and the user could be blocked to edit this post for few minutes... you don't think so?

Comment: @JoDev : I don't understand : It is completely automated when you are banned from flagging : It happen automatically when declined flags reach a percentage in recent flags : see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/242800 .

Comment: @user2284570 : You're right! Sorry for the lack of understanding! So yes, it will be a good idea, and it would does the trick!

Comment: @JoDev : Puisque très peu de gens votent pour votre qestion et que les « flag-bans » ont prouvé pleinement  leur efficacité : vous devriez vraiment mettre à jour votre question dès maintenant, en changeant votre proposition pour inclure l'autre possibilité comme alternative à votre suggestion. *(lacks of understanding from you : your native langage should be better)*

Comment: @user2284570 Thank you for helping me. I've changed the post to correctly highlight the `edit-bans` solution.
Was that what you asked me to do?
And about your last comment, thank you for the translation but what do you mean by "ont prouvé leur efficacité"? `flag-bans` already does the trick for you? And the answer will just be to add another particular `flag` to handle bad edit and not only bad post?

Comment: Should we really discard as ludicrous the (admittedly small) possibility that a) The proposer is right and therefore re-submits it or b) The proposer has no clue it was rejected instead of just not entered into the system (that *can* happen on some sites)? Maybe add a big warning if a previous edit on the same question was rejected (I don't know if it's already done)?

Comment: @user2284570 I really want to keep the idea that sometimes, user who make bad edit for a post can make a good one for another post! That why I think it will be great to ban just for the poorly edited post.