# Let me know when I can suggest edits again while being manually banned

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, edit-ban

When trying to suggest new edit, I saw this message:

> You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review your edit history

I reviewed my history, but found no recent rejected edits, so it probably means a [moderator manually banned me from suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252991/152859). Hence, I can't know when it started and when it will be over.

I would like to see for how long I am still banned, same way we can for example see for how long we are suspended.

Comment: What are you talking about? I don't see any recent rejected edits. You mean you can't suggest edits, or can't review? Or something else?

Comment: i am not able to edit question and answers

Comment: and thats what i wondering there are no rejected edits

Comment: So it means you were banned manually by a moderator. I fear there's no way to see for how long or when it expire, better change this question to feature request asking to add such a thing.

Comment: If you had no rejected edits, maybe a moderator gave you a manual suspension. A while ago, I proposed a [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit) on Meta Stack Overflow to help our editors.

Comment: @Lakhan well, your question here is really not clear, it's hard to understand what you mean and what you really want, that might be the reason for downvotes

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes i hope this feature will add soon

Comment: Please do NOT bump with pointless edits. You posted your request. Now the team might, or might not, do something - but adding a useless dot is not the correct way to bump in order to get more attention. If you're really eager to know when you'll be able to edit again, try contacting a moderator in chat.

Comment: @ShadowWizard actually i was trying to add more description but then i dint add,and by mistake i click on edit..and my ban is removed yesterday..and i am not trying to get attention bro

Comment: @Lakhan It's likely you made a bad edit suggestion (or a series of them). Weird because a moderator should've messaged you about any suspension/ban.

Comment: Just had a quick look through your edits, and I'm thinking it could have been caused by your pointless `backtick` edits. Words such as 'Android' do not need to be backticked.

Comment: @SelakaN you have to click on the link for more information. Here is the link, again, to the relevant answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252991/223820 and here also [**We now show suggested edit outcomes in the activity list**. … **For users whose last edit (or edits) have been rejected, they get that warning and a link to information on why. But not in their inbox, not as a notification, not as an interruption to something else they might have been doing**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/223820)