# Means of marking individual review outcomes as incorrect even after another edit has been made

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, review-abuse

A known problem is that sometimes bad suggested edits get approved. Moderators have a tool in the form of suggested edit bans to deal with this, but those bans aren’t always immediately appropriate.

I’d like to suggest the ability to mark an individual review outcome as incorrect from its review page, with that mark being taken into account in automated review bans (essentially counted as an audit failure) and in automated suggested edit bans, even when later edits prevent the mod Reject override from being used. It might be possible to apply this mark automatically in some cases, too, like when a “looks good” is later closed or deleted as spam/abusive.

In the case of suggested edits, it could also remove the 2-rep bonus.

Examples:

- [How was this edit useful?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368670/how-was-this-edit-useful)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14949337
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19975662 (when someone rolls back a harmful edit – the right thing to do – it prevents the mod Reject override from being used)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19968711
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20096687 (I don’t understand why this one can’t be overridden, actually – it’s the most recent revision. Normally whether the OP approved it doesn’t matter.)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20779577
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20762159
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20772319 (OP overriding *correct* decision by reviewers to reject the edit means mods can’t override again)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23332594 (edit to revert the edit substance check circumvention insta-approves and makes it impossible to reject after the fact)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194571/flag-users-who-approve-an-edit-that-ends-up-rejected-for-vandalism (This is maybe an improved suggestion? There are already a lot of flags to deal with, but this is just something that goes Into The System™.)

Comment: Ok, I'm not marking this as a duplicate because it is considerably more broad... But your specific example is done as of this spring: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028

Comment: @Shog9: Oh, right – thanks! I lock myself out of that a lot with rollbacks, though, so being able to do that without having it actually change the post would still be helpful.

Comment: I got... Complicated thoughts on that... But they'll have to wait for another day.

Comment: Got my support: this sounds like a slight twist on what I asked for here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272472/better-review-audits-better-review-ban-tools

Comment: @Shog9: I’ve gotten used to hitting Reject instead of rolling back now, but people still put edits over top of bad edits that got approved (makes sense). Could the button stick around in those cases and only affect the rep + displayed review outcome? Really, really need this feature.

Comment: It'd be tricky, @Ry- - post examples in your question here when you come across 'em.

Comment: @Shog9: Important enough to make Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368670/how-was-this-edit-useful If a moderator doesn’t get to it first, it stays approved.