# Mark edits as rejected and remove the corresponding reputation gain when rolling back over them

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Duplicate of [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back), acceptable compromise in [Means of marking individual review outcomes as incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297841/means-of-marking-individual-review-outcomes-as-incorrect), whatever. These haven’t been implemented, I’m out of rep to bounty, and it’s epidemic.

The process of dealing with persistent bad editors that keep getting unilaterally approved by inexperienced post authors needs to not involve so much moderator work.

Comment: Have an upvote so you get some bounty back.

Comment: What do you propose to do with persistent bad rollbackers that keep rolling back good edits?

Comment: @Glorfindel: Are there many of those? Anyway, when a rollback is rolled back over, toggle any reviews it toggled. =)